# how to get instance of angular service in javascript code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have an angular service. this is the code :

```
angular.module('myServiceModule', [])
    .service('angService',function({
     this.get=function(){
        console.log('i am accessible');
     }
});
```

i have to access `get()` method of angular service in javascript code(not from angular code).

```
<script>
  function caller(){
    //here i have to access service get() method.how is it possible.
    //can i do this->
    myServiceModule.get();
  }
 caller();//this function i am calling after service load.
</script>
```

i have done this. but it is not right. How is it possible ?

Comment: Do you need the same service instance the angular app is using?

Comment: yes, and i got the solution by @Mosho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
angular.injector(['ng', 'myServiceModule']).invoke(["myService", function(myService) {
    //do something with myService
}]);
```